# Find specific substrings from a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, find, substring

Say I have a string of a html source, and I want to write a loop to find all the links with a specific class name, for example:

```
<a class="i-e" href="DATA IM INTERESTED IN">
```

I would like to store all the links found into a list.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to HTML parser, implement string parser.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std ;

string html="<a class=\"i-e\" href=\"DATA IM INTERESTED IN\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"i-e\" href=\"ie like1\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"i-e\" href=\"ie like2\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"i-e\" style=\"font-size:10pt;\" href=\"ie like3\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"chrome\" href=\"nono chrome\">\n\
<a class=\"i-e\" href=\"ie like4\"> <a class=\"i-e\" href=\"ie like5\">\n\
";

int main() {
    smatch m, m2 ;
    regex e ( "class=\"i-e\"([^<>]+)>" ) ;  // get: href="ie like"
    regex e2 ( "href=\"(.+)\"" ) ;  // get ie like
    bool r, r2 ;

    string content ;

    int start=0 ;
    cout << "input html : " << html << endl ;
    do {
        content = html.substr(start) ;
//      cout << "content:"<<content<<endl;
        r=regex_search(content, m, e) ;
        if ( r ) {
//          cout << "search: " << r << endl ;
//          cout << "str: " << m.position() << " "<< m.str() << endl ;
            cout << "match : " << m[1] << endl ;
            r2 = regex_search((string)m[1], m2, e2) ;
            if ( r2 ) {
                cout << " URL : " <<m2[1]<<endl ;
            }
        }
        start+=m.str().length()+m.position();
    } while( r );

    return 0 ;
}
```

and output is this

```
input html : <a class="i-e" href="DATA IM INTERESTED IN">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="i-e" href="ie like1">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="i-e" href="ie like2">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="i-e" style="font-size:10pt;" href="ie like3">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="chrome" href="nono chrome">
<a class="i-e" href="ie like4"> <a class="i-e" href="ie like5">

match :  href="DATA IM INTERESTED IN"
 URL : DATA IM INTERESTED IN
match :  href="ie like1"
 URL : ie like1
match :  href="ie like2"
 URL : ie like2
match :  style="font-size:10pt;" href="ie like3"
 URL : ie like3
match :  href="ie like4"
 URL : ie like4
match :  href="ie like5"
 URL : ie like5
```

Comment: This is fine as long as your HTML document is well-known and decently well-behaved - in general you cannot parse HTML correctly with regexes (and especially the badly-broken HTML found "in the wild").

Answer (score -1):

1.start a loop until EOF
2. Catch the needed char/word & collect where you want ( a string list like CList).
3. Alternatively, the colected list nay be saved into another File

Comment: thanks  for advice - i am quite new bu here. as looking above, it might be said a post for negative points :)